# Do Defense Drones shoot down Flak projectiles?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The new Advanced FTL Edition offers many new things to the game, including Flak Weaponry. Do Defense Drones shoot down flak projectiles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, both defense drones can shoot down flak projectiles, but each piece is a separate target. The drone can get one or two pieces but it won't stop them all.

Comment: Does this apply to both the Mk I and Mk II?

Comment: @Max Yes. Edited it into the answer.

Answer (score -3):

I just tested it: Defense Drone Mark I does NOT shoot down Flak.

Comment: Welcome to arqade. Could you provide some evidence? Because it contradicts the accepted answer.